# How to set position properly in NIO.2's AsynchronousFileChannel.write(ByteBuffer src, long position)?

Tags: java, nio, nonblocking, java-7

My Java-program does a multithreaded XSLT Transformation and writes the results to a file. To avoid the IO bottleneck I am experimenting with the new AsynchronousFileChannel.
The XSLT-Threads should submit their output as strings (which works) and the Writer to append them to the file (that does not work yet).

I wrote a custom Writer-class for the write-operations. My Threads call the Writer.write(String text)-method. In there I would like to append the String as ByteBuffer to the AsynchronousFileChannel.
Unfortunately, I could find no hint what to use as the position value in asyncOutput.write(ByteBuffer, Long). I tried different values for position without success (Output gets scrambled). I am pretty sure, there is no problem with synchronization as the code works well with FileChannels (which do not support a simple non blocking io mode):

- asyncOutput.size()
- asyncOutput.size() + future.get().longValue()
- 0

Here's the code how I am trying to do this:

```
public class MyWriter {
private AsynchronousFileChannel asyncOutput;    

    MyWriter(String filename) throws IOException {
        asyncOutput = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get(filename), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
    }

    public void write(String output) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        System.err.println("Write was called");
        this.future = asyncOutput.write(string2ByteBuffer(output), asyncOutput.size());
    }

    public ByteBuffer string2ByteBuffer (String text){
    ...
    }
}
```

The method is called from a the XSLT-Threads (Runnable) like this:

```
synchronized (this) {
        this.write2Writer(outputXmlWriter.toString());
        }
...
private void write2Writer(String output) throws IOException {
    try {
        myWriter.write(output);
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution extracted from the link:

```
Future<Integer> future = asyncOutput.write(string2ByteBuffer(output), this.position);
this.position += future.get();
```

Source: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alanb/6830721/webrev.00/test/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel/Basic.java.html

Answer (score 1):

> I could find no hint what to use as the position value in
>   asyncOutput.write(ByteBuffer, Long)

It is the position you want to position at. I don't see what's so mysterious about it.

Comment: I just do not know how to determine the actual end of the file during the runtime of the program, so I can append new data without destroying the data already written.

Comment: @Andreas I doubt that you need to do this at all. Most probably what you should be doing is writing via a BufferedOutputStream or BufferedWriter. You can tune the buffer size of these if you wish but I have always found the defaults perfectly adequate.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Now I found out how to set position from this file: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~alanb/6830721/webrev.00/test/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel/Basic.java.html

Comment: As I got everything running, I could do some Benchmarks. And indeed, AsynchronousFileChannel was a little bit slower than a BufferedWriter with 50MB Buffer. So I am now using the BufferedWriter

Answer (score 1):

AsynchronousFileChannel does not have a global position, this is deliberate. Instead this channel provides an asynchronous API for applications that need to access different parts of a file at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see, I finally set up my own global Position inside the Writer-Class (this.position). And I can access & update this value on any write.